# ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to document() must be an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  brands: {
    type: [String],
    required: true,
  },
  priceRange: {
    type: [String],
    required: true,
  },
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phoneNumber: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: {
      validator: function(v) {
        return /^[0-9]{10}$/.test(v);
      },
      message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid phone number!`,
    },
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      validator: function(v) {
        return /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/.test(v);
      },
      message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid email address!`,
    },
  },
  demographicArea: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['male', 'female', 'others'],
    required: true,
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  pincode: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: {
      validator: function(v) {
        return /^[0-9]{6}$/.test(v);
      },
      message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid pincode!`,
    },
  },
  selectedCategories: [categorySchema],
});




const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

The above is the code for storing the form details along with the user selections on different category of products and its price Ranges and brands.

However when submitted I am encountered with an castError due to ObjectParameterError ,  ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to document() must be an object, got "camera"(type: string)

Comment: It looks like the error is somewhere else where `camera` is used